# How do I ask the db if there exist value so show the other value

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I need to do select option with values a, b, c for example

But if in the db exist value a then show only c and b

I have tried this but if the db table is empty then I want to show all the options

But it's not work for me if the table is empty it's don't show anything its work when there is value in the db

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $curr = $row['time'];
    if($curr === 'a') {
        echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>";
        echo "<option value='b'>b</option>";
        echo "<option value='c'>c</option>";
        echo "</select>";
    }
    if($curr === 'b') {
        echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>";
        echo "<option value='a'>a</option>";
        echo "<option value='c'>c</option>";
        echo "</select>";
    }
    if($curr === 'c') {
        echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>";
        echo "<option value='a'>a</option>";
        echo "<option value='b'>b</option>";
        echo "</select>";
    }
    if ($curr === '') {
        echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>";
        echo "<option value='a'>a</option>";
        echo "<option value='b'>b</option>";
        echo "<option value='c'>c</option>";
        echo "</select>";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is very important to know that the possible values of `$row['time']`

Comment: if you tried all example given below than share your query or complete code

Comment: we need to see the db's schema and values. If you have `NULL` as default values, then `NULL` is not considered as being "empty", it's still a value. We also do not know what your query is. Seeing the comments you left under answers, you have everyone guessing.

Comment: Voting as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an else that way the input can be `Null`

```
else{
    echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>";
    echo "<option value='a'>a</option>";
    echo "<option value='b'>b</option>";
    echo "<option value='c'>c</option>";
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the all the value options and then remove the relevant one:

```
$arrOptions = [
    'a' => "<option value='a'>a</option>",
    'b' => "<option value='b'>b</option>",
    'c' => "<option value='c'>c</option>";
];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $curr = $row['time'];

    if(isset($arrOptions[$curr])) {
        unset($arrOptions[$curr]);
    }

    echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>" . implode($arrOptions) . "</select>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that $curr is likely not a blank string and could be `NULL` which won't match because you've got `===` which means they must match exactly. You could solve it by simply checking if it is empty to cover all cases like `if (empty($curr)) { // show all options`

You could simplify the problem and reduce your code base by assigning your options in an array like the below:

```
$allOptions = [
    'a' => "<option value='a'>a</option>",
    'b' => "<option value='b'>b</option>",
    'c' => "<option value='c'>c</option>";
];
$hasOneRow = false;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $hasOneRow = true;
    $options = clone($allOptions);
    $curr = $row['time'];

    if(isset($options[$curr])) {
        unset($options[$curr]);
    } 

    echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>";
    echo implode(PHP_EOL, $options);
    echo "</select>";
}
if(!$hasOneRow) {
    echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>";
    echo implode(PHP_EOL, $allOptions);
    echo "</select>";
}
```

This assumes that each line is separate and if you have multiple records if your database you don't want to remove multiple options at once (ie: for each row there should be a select option without the option in the database contained in the options - and as requested it will show all options if there is nothing selected.

If your aim is to reduce the number of options for each row in the database that has been used, then you can use the code below which will only show the options remaining across all rows and shows all options if nothing is selected

```
$options = [
    'a' => "<option value='a'>a</option>",
    'b' => "<option value='b'>b</option>",
    'c' => "<option value='c'>c</option>";
];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $curr = $row['time'];

    if(isset($options[$curr])) {
        unset($options[$curr]);
    } 

}
if(!empty($options)) {
    echo "<select class='form-control' name='time'>";
    echo implode(PHP_EOL, $options);
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Can you let me know what it did or didn't show? Which suggestion did you try - using empty() or using the simplified script?

Comment: Ah ok - if there are no rows in your table, rather than no value in the column. I'll edit my code to handle this too.

Comment: I've updated my answer with two changes - the first shows a select option for each row in your table and will show and a single select box with all options if there are no rows - the second shows only the remaining options based on whats in your database (ie: if there are no rows, it shows all options, if A and B are in the database across two rows it will only show C, if A, B and C are in the table, it will show nothing)

Comment: Thanks @YosefDadya - can you mark it as the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try replacing `if ($curr === '')` with `if ( empty($curr) )` ?